# Display data json (plot.ly) from influxdb

Tags: python, json, matplotlib, plotly, influxdb

I'm trying to get a graph of my influxdb measurements.To display graphics, I use plot.ly and python. I started in python with a sql request to get my json data from localhost:8086, but it doesn't work. I've tried some things, I'm sending you my little piece of code:

```py
import plotly 
import plotly.plotly as py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as ply
import pandas as pd
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_json('http://localhost:8086/query?q=SELECT%20%22I%22%20FROM%20%22michelin%22.%22autogen%22.%22mqtt_consumer%22%20WHERE%20time%20%3E%20now()%20-%202d%20AND%20%22topic%22=%27PI1%27')
    print(df['results'])
    #df = [go.Scatter(x=df['time'], y=df['mqtt_consumer.mean_I'])]
    ply.plot(df, filename = 'time-series-simple')
```

The link with the request shows me this :

[image]

I would like a time series, with the value "I" as a function of time.
If anyone can help me, thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

You must unwind all the keys before plotting. The data inside the json object that you want to plot is at the innermost nested level. You need to reach that. Try this

```
dfff = pd.DataFrame(df["results"][0]["series"][0]["values"]).T
#dfff.plot()
```

Specifically if you want to plot using `plotly`:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfff = pd.DataFrame(df["results"][0]["series"][0]["values"]).T


dfff.columns = ["timestamp","value"]

py.iplot([{
    'x': dfff.timestamp,
    'y': dfff["value"],
    'name': "value"
}  ], filename='yourfilename')
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, I made a print, so I get my measurements back.
However, to display my graph on an html page, it doesn't work, it returns this to me:
 raise exceptions.PlotlyError("The `figure_or_data` positional"
Plotly_utils.exceptions.PlotlyError: The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure

I create the file with this command: 
ply.plot(dfff, filename = "time-series-simple")
with dfff my data

Comment: i guess to plot the dataframe values you need to explicitly give your `y` and `x`values. I made an edit , try it out.

Comment: Sorry for the response time
Thank you very much for your help, the problem is solved thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

To plot the data via Plot.ly, You need to create a trace first where you define the X, Y axis data.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace = go.Scatter(
x = ("Your X data, Must be a numpy array"),
y = ("Your Y data, Must be a numpy array"),
mode = 'markers'
)

data = [trace]
```

Then you can simply,

```
py.plot(data, filename='basic-line')
```